# Sum aggregation for MongoDB via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Before I begin, I want to state that no other answers regarding similar questions applied to this one. First consider the following JSON code

```
  "_id": "1412302013-01-20,11:32:22" 
  "display": [
    {
      "Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4",
      "Type": "Startup",
      "Count": 2,
      "Detail": [
        {
          "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
          "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30"
        },
        {
          "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
          "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "PUR-12-47-SH-X3.mp4",
      "Type": "Movie",
      "Count": "2",
      "Detail": [
        {
          "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
          "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30"
        },
        {
          "Start": "2013-01-20,11:32:22",
          "End": "2013-01-20,11:32:30"
        }
      ]
    },
```

The ID is basically a combination of a license plate number concatted with a time stamp.
What I am trying to do is aggregate the sum for `"Count"`, where the `"Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"`.

I could not even get simple sums to be aggregated, so trying to aggregate this sum has been impossible. When running my script in NodeJS, I either get `undefined` or `[object Object]`.

I have no clue what is going wrong as I've been following various online examples.

After trying to use parvin's answer below, I am still getting undefined:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {"display.Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"}},
    {$unwind : "$display"},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", 
               name : {$first : "$display.Name"}, 
               total : {$sum : "$display.Count"}
              }   
    }], function(err, result) {
    console.log("Aggregation: " + result.total);
});
```

I've been trying to format the code like these [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aggregate` callback's `result` parameter is an array, not a single value.  You can see this if you just dump out `result`:

```
console.log(result);
```

So to access `total` of the first doc in the array:

```
console.log(result[0].total);
```

But that's going to be 0 because `Count` in your doc is a string, not a number.  You can't `$sum` strings.

Because you also only want the `total` for only the `"Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"` elements, you need to add another filter after your `$unwind`:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {"display.Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"}},
    {$unwind : "$display"},
    {$match : {"display.Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"}},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", 
               name : {$first : "$display.Name"}, 
               total : {$sum : "$display.Count"}
              }   
    }], function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Interesting... so `$sum` doesn't actually give me a sum, forcing me to create a loop in order to add up all the array values.

Comment: @krikara The right way to fix this is to change your data so that `Count` is a number instead of a string.

Comment: Yeah I just changed Count to an actual number. But it still isn't a sum, so I still need the loop. I think that is what confused me the most, because in the Mongo shell it was actually a sum. But NodeJS just takes each individual value and stores it in the array.

Comment: Actually, I still didn't reach my goal. The aggregation code "sums" all the `Count` under display, but I was looking for the sum of the all the `Count` where `"Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"`.

Comment: @krikara See updated answer.  You need to `$match` again after the `$unwind` for that.

Comment: When I run this over 80,000 entries, my program crashes at the result line. Is there a limit on the size of result or perhaps a limit coming from the database? Anything less than 80,000 entries in my collection and my program will run just fine.

Comment: @krikara The `aggregate` result is [limited to 16 MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to find the total count for the `Name = "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"`. This is the javascript example, you have to convert it to node.js

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$match : {"display.Name" : "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"}},
    {$unwind : "$display"},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", 
               name : {$first : "$display.Name"}, 
               total : {$sum : "$display.Count"}
    }}
)
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I'm getting the following error. `TypeError: object is not a function`. I've also tried adding `function(err, count){` as well as putting it into array format, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated my JSON above. The aggregation code "sums" all the `Count` under display, but I was looking for the sum of the all the `Count` where `"Name": "LOG-11-05-SH-O1.mp4"`. Would this be possible?